# apt-secure manpage

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

When I did `sudo apt update`, the three last lines were

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/blueman/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I would like to get rid of that? Could anyone be able to tell me what should I do to realise such thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` or some file within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, you have a reference to some repository that does not provide packages for yakkety - nor any recent [ubuntu version](http://ppa.launchpad.net/blueman/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

You should be able to fix this error commenting out the corresponding line(s) from your configuration, then running `apt-get update` again.